# How to use FaceBook anonymously with Tor? Is it possible to use FaceBook without JavaScript?

Tags: anonymity, javascript

Is there any way to use FaceBook with JavaScript disabled? I would like to use FaceBook anonymously with Tor but FB requires JavaScript to be enabled and I read that it can be used to track my identity so in this case Tor wouldn't protect my privacy. Is it possible to safely use FaceBook with Tor? If not does that mean that nobody is and never will be anonymous to FaceBook?

Comment: Considering the purpose of Facebook, the question makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the facebook adress onion : 
https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion/

But you still need Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use facebook (facebookcorewwwi.onion) through Tor from within a Virtual Machine*.

[Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) allows it, as does [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/), which is meant for that type of use. Tails also wipes all memory it uses in order to prevent long term persistency-based deanonymization.

Qubes (https (colon) //www.qubes-os (dot) org/) might be usable for that kind of hardware-specs spoofing, but that would require reading the docs again.

*Some specific fingerprinting features based on GPU options most likely flatout won't work. Do ensure the virtualization engine you use doesn't expose your system's true specs.

Answer (score 0):

> How to use FaceBook anonymously with Tor?

Anonymously as in "Facebook doesn't know who you are", then no. You're required to provide a phone number to register, and you may get (in some cases) your account locked if they ask you to prove your identity.

> Is it possible to use FaceBook without JavaScript?

Yes, use the mobile version: https://m.facebookcorewwwi.onion/